# Selecting a max number of rows per group

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table of user records. It was allowed to have multiple entries for one email address. I now want to create a query that will return all the record, but limit the number of duplicate entries to a set number, for example 5 per email address.

The end result of this query I will use to create a new table.

The only thought I had was to use PHP and select a list of unique email addresses, then I  would use this list in loop to query the table and limit it to 5, but I have about 65k unique emails in my table and the total records about 284k rows.

Is there a way I can have this done in MySQL?

HERE is the table structure.

```
first_name, last_name, email
John, smith, js@email.com
john, smith, js@email.com
John, smith, js@email.com
john, smith, js@email.com
Jane, smith, jbs@email.com
jane, smith, jbs@email.com
Jane, smith, jbs@email.com
john, smith, js@email.com
```

I would like to get a query that returns the same records but limiting the duplicates to an parameter I can change. In the example above let's say a max of 2 duplicates is allowed. I want to get

```
first_name, last_name, email
John, smith, js@email.com
john, smith, js@email.com
Jane, smith, jbs@email.com
jane, smith, jbs@email.com
```

Hope this clarifies it a bit more.

thanks.

Comment: Can you show a sample data and what you need from it?

Comment: Use one of the many solutions to getting per-group row numbers, and then select only the rows with row <= 5.

Comment: Do you have an id column in your table?

Comment: yes there is an id column.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email
  FROM
(
  SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email,
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM users
     WHERE email = u.email
       AND user_id < u.user_id
  ) rnum     
    FROM users u
) q
 WHERE rnum <= 2 -- change 2 to a number of duplicates you need
 ORDER BY email, user_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0927c/5)** demo